# Calling EF Core HasIndex from F#

Tags: f#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to rewrite a C# EF Core example (similar to [the one in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes)) into F#. I have a problem with [HasIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.hasindex?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder%601.HasIndex);k(DevLang-FSharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-2.0). In C#, the call is `HasIndex(b => b.Isbn)`, to create an index on the Isbn column:

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasIndex(b => b.Isbn);
    }
}
```

Doing the same in F#, `HasIndex(fun b -> b.Isbn)`, doesn't compile:

```
type public SampleContext() =
    inherit DbContext()

    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable books: DbSet<Book>

    member x.Books
        with get() = x.books
        and set v = x.books <- v

    override __.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) =
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasIndex(fun b -> b.Isbn) // doesn't compile
        |> ignore
```

Do I need to use some quotation magic to make this work?

(You can of course use a string, `HasIndex("Isbn")`, but I'd prefer not to throw compile time checks out the window.)

Comment: When you say "doesn't compile", it helps to include the exact compiler error you see. Without it, I _guess_ you'll need to wrap the `fun b -> b.Isbn` in <@ @> and convert the resulting `Expr` into `Expression` with this https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/leafexpressionconverter.quotationtolambdaexpression%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @HonzaBrestan Yes, `LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToLambdaExpression <@ Func<_, _>(fun (i: Book) -> i.Isbn :> obj) @>` did the trick. If you write that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: What happens if you use: "modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasIndex( (fun b -> b.Isbn :> System.Object ) )" instead? it seems to compile in my computer on .net core 2.0

Comment: @JuanTarquino: Yes, it works and the index is created! I thought quotations were necessary, but somehow F# figures it out without them (if you cast b.Isbn to Object). I'll mark that as accepted if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the accepted answer in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0757965-4d13-4f88-910f-9ab5fd96277d/how-to-convert-c-linq-expression-in-f?forum=fsharpgeneral:

"F# 3.0 or later should apply a type-directed conversion when you pass a lambda where an Expression is expected."

It seems that F# 3.0 and later will convert the lambda as long as you enclose it with parenthesis and cast the return value to the specific type that the C# method is expecting (in this case "Sytem.Object")

So:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasIndex( (fun b -> b.Isbn :> System.Object ) )
```

Compiles successfully in .net core 2.0